# Solr join not working on solr cloud environment

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

For Eg: I have 2 shards in solr cloud environment, My query is like  `http://localhost:8983/solr/B/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&fq={!join from=id to=uid fromIndex=A}type:xxx`

Now what happens while retrieving data from collection B the query only searching in the shard which gave data for the join query {!join from=id to=uid fromIndex=A}type:xxx

meaning if the document is found in shard 2 for collection A, the query is only searching the data in shard 2 even for collection B also.

Answer (score 0):

Try merging the queries to include both the collections.

> localhost:8983/solr/B/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&fq={!join
>   from=id to=uid
>   fromIndex=A}type:xxx,localhost:8983/solr/A/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&fq={!join
>   from=id to=uid fromIndex=B}